# criterion for dense subrings

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory, topological-rings

Let $R$ be a topological ring and $S$ a subring of $R$.  Also let $X$ be a subset of $R$ such that the ideal generated by $X$ is all of $R$.

If $X \subset \bar{S}$, can we prove that $S$ is dense in $R$?

Answer (score 1):

Since the ideal generated by $X$ is the smallest ideal containing $X$, it follows that $\bar{S} = R$ whenever $\bar{S}$ is an ideal. This would imply $S$ is necessarily dense in $R$.

What isn't as clear to me however is that $\bar{S}$ must be an ideal *a priori.* Even if $S$ is a subring it does not imply $S$ is an ideal. Why then must $\bar{S}$ be an ideal?

Comment: You're right, it may not be. For example, take $R=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, and $X=S=\bar{S}=\mathbb{Z}$.